# Existence of a maximal left ideal not containing a non-invertible element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> I'm trying to show that if $R$ is a ring with unity and $u \in R$ is not invertible, then there exists a maximal left ideal $L$ such that $u \notin L$.

I tried the following: I considered the poset of the left ideals such that $u \notin I$ and applied Zorn's lemma to obtain $L$, it remains to show that $L$ is maximal. This happens if and only if $1 \in L+Ru$. But I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: In a commutative ring, if $u \neq 0$ is a zero divisor then $u$ is contained in every maximal ideal, so your maximal ideal $L$ does not exist. Could it be that the problem is to find a left ideal $L$ that is maximal in the set of ideals that do not contain $u$? (Which is exactly what you have done.)

Comment: @RobArthan I don't think a zero divisor belongs to any maximal ideal. For instance, $R=\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ has two maximal ideals and $(1,0)$ belongs to only one of them. Instead, one can use every element in the Jacobson radical or even $u=0$. (The OP didn't suppose that $u\ne0$.)

Comment: @user26857: You are right. I meant to write "nilpotent" not "zero divisor". Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "there exists a maximal left ideal such that $u\notin L$" is ambiguous. Interpreted literally, the ideal has to be a maximal ideal in the whole ring, and $u\notin L$. But this is false: for rings with nonzero Jacobson radical, there are nonzero elements that are in all maximal left ideals (and they cannot be invertible.)

That is why it seems likely that your actual problem is to find a left ideal $L$ maximal *with respect to not containing u*.

That is certainly possible to apply Zorn's lemma to, and the conclusion is that there is such an ideal, but after that there is nothing left to prove about maximality: that was given to you by Zorn's lemma.